# defining _WINSOCKAPI_ causes error in visual studio 2012 migration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, winsock

So I'm trying to update a windows build of a project and encountered this error,

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\ws2def.h(452): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\ws2def.h(452): error C3805: 'constant': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
```

I determined that winsock.h must have been included earlier than Winsock2.h which was included in the error'd file so I defined

```
_WINSOCKAPI_
```

in the project properties to make sure that didn't happen.

However now I get like 8 other errors from files that include afxsock.h saying "error : MFC requires use of Winsock2.h".  So is

```
_WINSOCKAPI_
```

preventing afxsock.h from including winsock?  Because it seems like I have this circular error and only one set of files can build properly.

Comment: Defining `_WINSOCKAPI_` disables `winsock.h`, it has no effect on `winsock2.h`.  `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` do not co-exist. If `winsock2.h` is included first, it disables `winsock.h`. But if `winsock.h` is included first, `winsock2.h` will not compile as it redeclares most of what `winsock.h` already declares (bad Microsoft!). If code needs `winsock2.h`, it should be using an `#include <winsock2.h>` statement to enforce that.

Comment: IoW, rather than messing with macro definitions, find the line in your code that is including `winsock.h` and get rid of it.